# Removing files from request before passing to controller

Tags: laravel, image, controller

I am doing image upload in my Laravel application where after selecting some images I want to remove some selected images , I have done that but when submitting ,the request still has all the images selected at the beginning.

Comment: Could you post what you did here please?

Comment: ok I will tell clearly... I am doing an image uploading functionality in my laravel application. then user can select as many images as he need.later before submitting the form if the user wishes to remove one or two images from his selection,he can do it..but the problem is when sumbitting the form after removing some images...the form still has all the images in its request parameter when seen from the controller side..

What i need i need to unlink the files deselected by the user from the client side itself and then sent to server side...so as to reduce the load

Answer (score -1):

What are the changes on your code from the first group of selections to the second?

Comment: In first selection, I selected 10 photos. Then I unselected 3 of them. Therefore currently I need to send only 7 of them to the server.